# log log model where dependent variable is 0

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

I am fitting log log models (e.g. [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rN8LlLOvpgk) or [non video link](http://www.dummies.com/education/economics/econometrics/econometrics-and-the-log-log-model/)) like these (very much simplified):

```
log(y) = intercept + parameter * log(x);
```

I have a few rows were y = 0. Just wondering what to do with those rows? Should I simple impute a small value (e.g. 0.1)?

Comment: I have never heard of these models, but be aware that these small values (also called "pseudocounts") are arbitrary and can have great impact on your fit, so always do try out several values of them to see how they affect the model.

Comment: 1. Do you really mean "log(y)=log(x)"? There's no parameters in that, for a start. 2. Are your data counts?

Comment: I edited the question and also added a link to more log log model details.

Comment: There is irony here in that the model in other terms is the power function or power law $y = ax^b$. $y = 0$ for such a model implies $x = 0$ so long as $b > 0$ but the logarithm of 0 is indeterminate. Perhaps explain why you think a power function is appropriate when some values are 0. (No connection here with power as discussed in hypothesis testing.)  Small point: the terminology "log log" here seems strange, regardless of your link; personally, I won't watch a video to respond to a question.  I'd suggest power function or power law.

Comment: I have edited my question to provide a non video link as well. Unfortunately, I am currently forced to use this model structure.

Comment: Who's **forcing** you to do this? You can minimally note that $ x = 0, y = 0$ points are consistent with the model and $x \neq 0, y = 0$ are not (as above assuming that $b > 0$).

Comment: log(0) is still -infinity and I have to do something practical to solve this. To do log(y + 1) is something practitioner tend to do.

Comment: You could try fitting the power function with weighted least squares and without taking logarithms.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to ignore those values if there are only few of them and a lot of other values.
Specifically values with flat 0 can't really help you fit this model anyways and maybe there is not reason to try and fit with them.

Comment: Would this not seriously bias the estimates?!